# PowerMock expectNew won't return a mock instance

Tags: java, powermock, easymock

I'm working with PowerMock to capture a constructor call that takes place inside the object I want to test. I've rigged up an example here that basically mimics what I want to do in my bigger example. I've found other answers to similar questions on SO, and I think I'm following the advice in the answers, but something appears to be off. Here is my example:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

import static org.easymock.EasyMock.*;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class Inner {
    public Inner(String one, String two, Boolean three) {
        System.out.println("Calling inner constructor");
    }

    public String saySomething() {
        return "something";
    }
}

class Outer {
    private Inner inner;

    public Outer(String arg) {
        this.inner = new Inner(arg, "foo", Boolean.TRUE);
    }

    public String getInnerString() {
        return this.inner.saySomething();
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Outer.class, Inner.class})
class PowerMockTest {

    @Test
    void testMockConstructor() throws Exception {
        Inner innerMock = mock(Inner.class);

        PowerMock.expectNew(Inner.class, anyObject(String.class), anyObject(String.class), anyObject(Boolean.class)).andReturn(innerMock);
        expect(innerMock.saySomething()).andReturn("something else");

        PowerMock.replay(innerMock, Inner.class);

        Outer outer = new Outer("foo");
        String s = outer.getInnerString();

        PowerMock.verify(innerMock, Inner.class);

        assertEquals("something else", s);
    }

}
```

When I run this test, I get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
  Expectation failure on verify:
    Inner.saySomething(): expected: 1, actual: 0
```

If I put an `assert` inside the `replay` block, it mismatches, saying that it expected `something else` but found `something`.

So basically, it seems to have caught the constructor call, but it still invokes the real constructor (which I don't want it to do) and calls `saySomething` on the actual instance instead of the mock one.

What am I missing?

Comment: In the example you showed, `Inner` is _purely_ an implementation detail of `Outer` and thus should be invisible to testing. If your example does not accurately reflect the relationships in your code, please update it. (In general, the usual appropriate answer is to replace the `new` with something like a `Supplier` or `Function`.)

Comment: In this example, `Inner` represents a class that establishes a connection to a message broker. It takes a `String` URL and then creates an internal instance of a class to connect to that URL. Here I'm trying to replace that object with a mock so that it doesn't try to connect to the message broker and instead I can inject mocked behavior.

Comment: As is often the case with unit testing, I ultimately had to just re-jigger my code so it could be tested. I made an alternate constructor that takes a ready-made message broker connection and made it private. Then I made a static factory method that takes a URL and constructs an instance using the private constructor. So I can feed it a mock connection for my unit test and the "untested" part is as lean as possible. This doesn't really answer the underlying question, though, so I'm leaving this open to see if there's a way to do it the way I was trying it.